# Extract only uppercase text from db field

Tags: database, sqlite, text-extraction

I "inherited" a db with a field in a table where there are lowercase and uppercase mixed together, eg.

```
gateway 71, HOWARD BLVD, Chispa, NY
```

They aren't easily "splittable" with code because they don't always come in this form. What I need is a way to extract only uppercase letters. Is this possible with SQLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case where it may just be easier (and perhaps quicker) to SELECT with any additional WHERE requirements you may have and create a cursor to iterate over the results doing your uppercase checks in code.

Another option with SQLite would be to create a [custom function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html), so you could do something like:

```
SELECT foo WHERE MYISALLUPPERFUNC(foo) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

As [NuSkooler mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265745/42346), this is probably easier and faster to do using a cursor; an especially attractive option if you will only have to do this once.

Here's a quick example (using built-in SQLite from Python REPL):

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as conn:
    conn.execute('''create table t (c, newc);''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.execute('''insert into t (c) values (?);''', ('testing MAIN ST',))
    conn.commit() 
    results = conn.execute('select c from t;').fetchall()
    for line in results:
        tokens = line[0].split()
        filtered_tokens = [i for i in tokens if i.isupper()]
        newc = ' '.join(filtered_tokens)
        conn.execute('update t set newc = ?;',(newc,))
        conn.commit()

    conn.execute('''select c,newc from t;''').fetchone()
    # (u'testing MAIN ST', u'MAIN ST')
```

Comment: I think he wants to extract the uppercase words and not turn them all into uppercase.